# Cordova Yahoo Oauth in javascript

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, oauth-2.0, yahoo-api

I am trying to use the Yahoo Oauth 2.0 for my cordova / ionic app.  Below is the providerUrl I am using for my rest call but I get an error that says something wrong has happened.

```
var providerUrl = 'https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/request_auth?client_id=' + clientId;
providerUrl += '&redirect_uri=' + redirect_uri;
providerUrl += '&response_type=token';
providerUrl += '&scope=' + appScope.join(" ");
```

My redirect uri is var redirect_uri = "http://localhost/callback";